# Create an array of string from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to create arrays from the following strings:

```js
"[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]" // ["DHKSGFKDBF", "JDKDFJ", "NDKDHDLSJD"]
"[ADJDJKDFJ][JEJZJDUDU]"           // ["ADJDJKDFJ", "JEJZJDUDU"]
"[ADJDJKDFJ]"                      // ["ADJDJKDFJ"]
```

There is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways to do it. Easiest would be remove the outside one and split.

```js
var str = "[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]"
var arr = str.slice(1,str.length-1).split('][');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ...or the other way around: `.split(/[\[\]]+/).slice(1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]"
var array = str.substring(1,str.length-1).split("][");
console.log(array);
```

results into:

```
["DHKSGFKDBF", "JDKDFJ", "NDKDHDLSJD"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have checked the correct format of the string (*i.e.* starting with `[` and ending with `]`), you could remove the leading `[` and the closing `]` and split by `][`, *e.g.*:

```js
[
  "[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]",
  "[ADJDJKDFJ][JEJZJDUDU]",
  "[ADJDJKDFJ]",
  ""
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(splitStr(str));
});

function splitStr(str) {
  if (str && str.length > 2 && str.charAt(0) == '[' && str.charAt(str.length - 1) == ']') {
    return str.substring(1, str.length - 1).split('][');
  }
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all non-alphanumeric characters (`/\W+/g`) with a delimiter (`,`), split on the delimiter, and then filter out the nulls (`!v`) at the beginning and end.

```js
const inputs = [
  "[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]", // ["DHKSGFKDBF","JDKDFJ","NDKDHDLSJD"]
  "[ADJDJKDFJ][JEJZJDUDU]",           // ["ADJDJKDFJ","JEJZJDUDU"]
  "[ADJDJKDFJ]"                       // ["ADJDJKDFJ"]
]

const convert = s => s.replace(/\W+/g, ',').split(',').filter(v => !!v);

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(JSON.stringify(convert(input))));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.match` function.

```js
var str = "[DHKSGFKDBF][JDKDFJ][NDKDHDLSJD]";
console.log(str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g).map(item => item.substring(1, item.length - 1)));
```